# Best way check if delegate responds to optional selector

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I've got used wrapping sending `@optional` delegate's methods into:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method:)]) {
    [self.delegate method:obj];
}
```

It works well, but if there are lot of delegate's methods, it looks like duplicating `respondToSelector:` code...

At some point of time I've put `respondsToSelector:` to separate method:

```
//ignore warning
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

- (void)performDelegateSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:selector withObject:obj];
    }
}
```

As a result I have just one respondToSelector: check, but It still doesn't look like well improved.

```
[self performDelegateSelector:@selector(method:) withObject:self];
```

What do you think? Does it make sense in using some helpers or category to wrap sending all `@optional` delegate's methods, or it's something that shouldn't be improved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Performance-wise it depends on what use you make of the delegate, whether it's directly affecting the UI (in which case you want to have faster response times) etc.

A good speed optimization is to register all of the methods implemented by the delegate in a data structure when you first set the delegate. You could do:

```
struct {
    unsigned int myFirstMethod:1;
    unsigned int mySecondMethod:1;
} delegateRespondsTo;

-(void)setDelegate:(id<MyProtocol>)delegate
{
    self.delegate = delegate;
    delegateRespondsTo.myFirstMethod = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myFirstMethod)];
    delegateRespondsTo.mySecondMethod = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mySecondMethod)];
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
if ( delegateRespondsTo.myFirstMethod )
    [self.delegate myFirstMethod];
```

Check this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626946/2274491) for a more exhaustive explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a trampoline for this. A trampoline is an object that forwards messages to another object. Here's a simple DelegateTrampoline.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface DelegateTrampoline : NSObject
- (id)initWithProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol delegate:(id)delegate;
@end
```

---

```
#import "DelegateTrampoline.h"

@interface DelegateTrampoline ()
@property (nonatomic) Protocol *protocol;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
@end

@implementation DelegateTrampoline

- (id)initWithProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol delegate:(id)delegate {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _protocol = protocol;
    _delegate = delegate;
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
  // Look for a required method
  struct objc_method_description desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(self.protocol, selector, YES, YES);
  if (desc.name == NULL) {
    // Maybe it's optional
    desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(self.protocol, selector, NO, YES);
  }
  if (desc.name == NULL) {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:selector]; // Raises NSInvalidArgumentException
    return nil;
  }
  else {
    return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:desc.types];
  }
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
  SEL selector = [invocation selector];
  if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [invocation setTarget:self.delegate];
    [invocation invoke];
  }
}

@end
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
@interface MyObject ()
@property (nonatomic) id delegateTrampoline;
@end
...
self.delegateTrampoline = [[DelegateTrampoline alloc] initWithProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)
                                                              delegate:delegate];

[self.delegateTrampoline myobject:self didSomethingAtIndex:1];
@end
```

Some notes:

- This is very slow compared to other approaches. It requires creating an `NSInvocation` object, which can be hundreds of times slower than a simple method call. That said, unless you're calling your delegate method in a tight loop, it's probably not a problem.
- You must declare `delegateTrampoline` to be of type `id`. This allows you to pass arbitrary selectors to it. But it also means that the compiler cannot detect if you pass a selector to `delegateTrampoline` that is not in the protocol. You'll crash at runtime if you do this. The compiler can detect if you pass a totally unknown selector, so it'll catch simple typos.

Comment: sounds good, but I meant - how to reduce amount of code, but not to reduce the performance.. And if there are lot of delegate's methods are executed, it can affects app perofrmance

Comment: If by lots you mean a dozen or two dozen calls, this will have no significant impact on performance. If you lots you mean hundreds or thousands of calls in a tight loop, then yes, then it might have a performance impact. The difference between a nanosecond and a millisecond is massive, but on a dozen calls you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: I've found similar approach here http://borkware.com/rants/agentm/elegant-delegation/
using NSProxy

Answer (score 1):

On top of answer provided by [@micantox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274491/micantox) I would add that instead of `struct` you could use `NS_OPTIONS` to define a `bitmask`.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS (NSUInteger, MyDelegateOptions) 
{ 
  MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskOne = 1 << 0,
  MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskTwo = 1 << 1,
  MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskThree = 1 << 2
};
```

You could then create property that can hold `bitmask`:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) MyDelegateOptions delegateOptions;`

and do check if delegate `respondsToSelector:`in your setter like

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<MyDelegateProtocol>)delegate
{
  _delegate = delegate;
  if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateDidFinishedWithTaskOne:)]) {
  {
    self.delegateOptions = self.delegateOptions | MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskOne;
  }

  if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateDidFinishedWithTaskTwo:)]) {
  {
    self.delegateOptions = self.delegateOptions | MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskTwo;
  }

  if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateDidFinishedWithTaskThree:)]) {
  {
    self.delegateOptions = self.delegateOptions | MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskThree;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply check assigned bit patterns by using `bitwise AND`

```
if (self.delegateOptions & MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskOne) {
    [self.delegate myDelegateDidFinishedWithTaskTwo:myResult];
}
```

As you can see use of `bitwise AND` will return `true` if bit for `MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskOne` is set as **1** even when other bits are set as well.

So if you assume that `delegate` was checked in your setter and based on this your `delegateOptions` holds bit pattern of **00000111** and your `MyDelegateOptionDidFinishedWithTaskOne` represents bit pattern of **00000001** then by simply using `bitwise AND`

> 00000111 & 00000001 = 00000001

you'll get `true` with your conditional statement.

It is worth notting that this is overkill in situations when you need to check your `delegate` only once or twice.